# Set range in excel

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set a range based off my current active cell and .Endshiftdown and .endshiftRight but I can not get the code right. Here is what I have but it does not compile with VB.Net.

```
Dim rRange As Excel.Range
rRange = Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0), _
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight))
rRange.Select()
```

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work"?

Comment: I mean It was a VBA code and does not work in VB.net and I can't get it to work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Meaning ActiveCell part of the code is not an option in VB.net

Comment: Why in the world could you not say that??????? Please edit your question to say what you actually mean. I think you mean that the above code does not compile.

Comment: Yes, it works in VBA but im having trouble getting it to work in VB.net